# How to add an int array in a protobuf message

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have to compose a protobuf message which should have 1 integer variables and a integer array.

```
package protobuf;

message myProto {

optional uint32 message_id =1;
optional int update = 2;
//here I have to add a array of integers
//can I write like     optional int[] array =3;
//or should I use      optional repeated array;
//where array is another message with int variable

}
```

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Array is mapped via "repeated":

```
 repeated int32 data = 4;
```

Note you might want sint32/uint32. Also note that in all three cases "packed arrays" can be used, which are more efficient;

```
repeated int32 data = 4 [packed=true];
```

Comment: is the packed array concept applicable for double arrays also?

Comment: can I write optional repeated double data = 4 [packed = true];

Comment: @Ravi yes, IIRC double is fine. But not strings or sub-messages, IIRC. For full coverage, the language guide goes into more.

Comment: in above 4  is tag or array size ?

Comment: @Raj tag; the size of the data is determined solely at runtime by how much data is there; there are no fixed sized arrays in protobuf. In the case of "packed", the size (in bytes) is prefixed to the data.

Comment: @MarcGravell so packed is a space optimisation. Would un-packed arrays be faster? Just curious if you have any information on the reason you would go one way or the other.

Comment: Update: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 states "In proto3, repeated fields of scalar numeric types use packed encoding by default."

Comment: @Jason very true (I wrote a different reply, then realised the question was purely about .proto schema, not the thing I was talking about)